# How to write nested if or case to make a prompted input menu?

Tags: if-statement, case, processing, arduino, nested-if

I'm working on an experience design project for one of my classes using a rotary phone and arduino kit to create a game based on automated phone menus. Serial input from the rotary dial is running through arduino and now I am using processing to write the menu.

I have an outline of actions and have started to code some if then statements to get going but now I have stumbled upon case and switch.

I am completely new to this but have learned a lot in class.

My question is how do I make a continuous set of nested if/then statments OR use case and switch to move through a series of prompts and inputs?

Here is my sketch so far:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;  // Create object from Serial class
float val;    // Data received from the serial port

boolean task1prompted;
boolean task1;
boolean task2;
boolean dialed;

PFont font;

void setup() {
    size(800, 400);
    background(0, 0, 0);
    smooth();
    // IMPORTANT NOTE:
    // The first serial port retrieved by Serial.list()
    // should be your Arduino. If not, uncomment the next
    // line by deleting the // before it. Run the sketch
    // again to see a list of serial ports. Then, change
    // the 0 in between [ and ] to the number of the port
    // that your Arduino is connected to.
    //println(Serial.list());
    String arduinoPort = Serial.list()[0];
    port = new Serial(this, arduinoPort, 9600);

    task1 = false;
    task2 = false;
    task1prompted = false;

    font = createFont("Arial", 32);
    textFont(font, 32);
    textAlign(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
    if (port.available() > 0) { // If data is available,
        val = port.read();      // read it and store it in val
        if (val >= 48 && val <= 57) {
            val = map(val, 48, 57, 0, 9);  // Convert the value
        }
        println(val);
    }

    if (val == 97) {
        println("dialing");
    }

    if (val == 98){
        println("dialed");
        dialed = true;
    }

    /// switch will activate the task1 variable.
    // Play sound file for the prompt.
    if (task1prompted == false){
      delay(1000);
       println("for spanish, press one. for french, press 2...");
      task1prompted = true;
    }

    task1 = true;

    if (task1 == true && dialed == true) {
        ///play sound file

        if (val == 5) {
            println("Thank you for playing... Blah blah next prompt.");
            dialed = true;
            task1=false;
            task2=true;
        } else
            if (val != 5) {
            println("We're sorry, all of our international operators are busy");
            task1 = true;
            task2 = false;
            dialed = false;
        }

    }
    else
        if (task2 == true){
            delay(1000);
            println("task2 start");
        }
}
```

My instructor helped me to get this far and I have been scouring for answers on how to keep going on to the next task/prompt. Would it be easier to use case and switch? And am I even doing nested if statements the right way?

Well I just tried this out with sketch and case commands as follows:

```java
    /// Switch will activate the task1 variable.
    //  Play sound file for the prompt.
    if (task1prompted == false){
        delay(1000);
        println("for spanish, press one. for french, press 2...");
        task1prompted = true;
    }

    task1 = true;

    if (task1 == true && dialed == true) {
        ///Play sound file

        int lang = (int)(val+0);

        switch(lang) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                println("sorry no international operators");  // If 1-4 go back to choices
                task1 = true;
                task2 = false;
                dialed = false;
                break;
            case 5:
                println("thank you, move to next prompt");  // If 5 go to next prompt
                task1=false;
                task2=true;
                dialed = true;
                break;
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 0:
                println("not a valid option, you lose");  // If not 1-5 go back to beginning
                task1=false;
                task2=false;
                dialed = true;
                break;
        }

        if (task2prompted == false){
            delay(1000);
            println("please listen while we test the line");
            task2prompted = true;
        }

        task2 = true;

        if (task2 == true && dialed == true) {
        } ///Play sound file

        int tone = (int)(val+0);

        switch(tone) {
          case 1:
          case 2:
          case 3:
          case 5:
          case 6:
          case 7:
          case 8:
          case 9:
          case 0:
            println("not a valid connection, you lose");  // If not 4 go back to beginning
            task2 = false;
            task3 = false;
            dialed = false;
            break;
          case 4:
            println("thank you, move to next prompt");  // If 4 move to next prompt
            task2=false;
            task3=true;
            dialed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still confused on how to make this have levels and not all happen simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look up [finite state machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478972.aspx).  It's a pretty common approach to dealing with event driven user interfaces.

Comment: If you google the terms Arduino and Finite State Machines, you'll find a lot of relevant answers. See https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/FiniteStateMachine for a library that may make your work easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is but maybe something here will answer it, if not just clarify what you're looking for

With case statements you don't need to make a case for every single output that can happen.  the way you can avoid doing that is by using a default statement

Example:

```
    switch(tone) {
      case 4:
        println("thank you, move to next prompt");  // If 4 move to next prompt
        task2=false;
        task3=true;
        dialed = true;
        break;
      default:
        println("not a valid connection, you lose");  // If not 4 go back to beginning
        task2 = false;
        task3 = false;
        dialed = false;
    }
```

The default case doesn't need a break because it is at the end.  But essentially it is the catch all case if nothing else is hit.

Also in some of your code above

```
if (val == 97) {
    println("dialing");
}

if (val == 98){
    println("dialed");
    dialed = true;
}
```

it is better to use an "else if" to make it not have to check through both if one is correct

```
if (val == 97) {
    println("dialing");
}

else if (val == 98){
    println("dialed");
    dialed = true;
}
```